# Not able to RDP on a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am trying to RDP into an EC2 instance from my windows 7 machine however always gets

Remote Desktop Can't Connect to remote Comupter for one of these resons

1.) Remote Desktop to server is not enabled

2.) The remote Computer is turnnned off

3.) The remote computer is not avilable on the network.

I am able to RDP other EC2 instance. also a as work-around I am able to RDP into the subjected instance from other EC2 machine but not from my windows 7 machine and also other machine on the network.

Checked the security GROUP of both RDP-working and RDP-non-working ec2 instance and they are configured identical (port 3389 enabled).

Any suggestion please!!!!

Comment: Restart your ec2 instance and then try to RDP.

Comment: From my experience, a Windows EC2 instance usually takes about 15 minutes to get access via RDP. For linux instances, it is usually immediate. Never understood why.

Comment: @VaibhavDesai There is extra setup taking place on initial launch for windows instances (sysprep, etc.).

Comment: A medium instance only took about 5 minutes for me before I was able to RDP in.

Answer (score 7):

1. In the AWS console, edit your security group or create a new one and add a new Inbound rule: "All Traffic" and Custom IP = {Your IP}
2. Go to the instance you want to connect to and press Connect and download the Remote Desktop File or open it from the web browser.
3. In the same screen as in point 2 (Connect to your instance), click on Get Password and uploaded your .pem file directory that you should have downloaded earlier and decrypt my password
4. Sign into the RDP using Administrator for the username and that password.

It's important to note that your default security group in AWS does not allow RDPing, which is why step 1 is important here.

Comment: I just moved house and couldn't connect, this solved it as result of updating my IP address. Rookie stuff - but I am a rookie so this saved me an expensive trip to Amazon tech support - thank you!!

Comment: crazy but it doesn't connect. This crap happens to AWS all the time. Azure never has these kind of problems

Comment: had to delete all EC2 and VPC and re-do again, that did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have already tried and tested all the above suggestions like-

1. Verifying whether your instance have the RDP protocol step correctly or not.
2. Added a new inbound rule i.e. a Custom TCP port(i.e. 3389) in your security group.

If you still have the issue, the one thing you can try is to check you **xrdp.ini** file (for ubuntu it is located at /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini) should contain the port field as **port=ask-1** if it contains any other value( for example **port=askaskaskask-1** that means you had run the setup commands more than once) change it to **port=ask-1**.

Answer (score 0):

Before connecting through RDP you need to create an Inbound Rule type RDP (TCP on Port 3389) on "Security Groups". You can either add it to the existing security group or create a new group, BUT if you create a new security group you must go to "Network Interfaces", select the interface, go to Actions > Change Security Group and include the new group.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same problem. Please follow the steps

Open the RDP port (3389) in AWS instance security group inbound rules.

- For windows- Check RDP port is opened or not in the local system
  windows firewall. If not opened, please open it.
- For Linux - Allow the RDP port in the Linux server as well. Use the
  following command.

  **`sudo ufw allow 3389/tcp`**